# r convert data frame to list of lists

Tags: r

Given the following data frame:

```
Date       Person   Article
---------------------------
01-01-2015 Bob      TV
01-01-2015 Bob      Video
01-01-2015 Pete     Book
02-01-2015 Rob      Skate
02-01-2015 Kate     TV
```

How could I convert this data frame to a list of list (or multidimensional array) so, that

```
my_ist[[01-01-2015]][[Bob]]
```

would give

```
TV, Video
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this?

```
res <- lapply(split(df, df$V1), function(x) sapply(split(x, x$V2), function(y) y$V3))
res[["01-01-2015"]][["Bob"]]
[1] "TV"    "Video"
```