# grouped data frame to list

Tags: r, dplyr

I've got a data frame that contains names that are grouped, like so:

```
df <- data.frame(group = rep(letters[1:2], each=2),
                 name = LETTERS[1:4])
> df
  group name
1     a    A
2     a    B
3     b    C
4     b    D
```

I would like to convert this into a list that is keyed on the group names and contains the names. Example output:

```
df_out <- list(a=c('A', 'B'),
               b=c('C', 'D'))

> df_out
$a
[1] "A" "B"

$b
[1] "C" "D"
```

This is [not a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34375162/r-convert-data-frame-to-list-of-lists) but I would like to do this wholly within the tidyverse.

Comment: Try `split(df$name,df$group)`

Comment: The tidyverse still consists of R packages. Thus, using base functions and using the tidyverse is not mutually exclusive. You probably got downvoted (not by me) for wanting to reinvent a well known easy to use base function.

Comment: You _could_ do it with some variation of `library(tidyverse) ; library(magrittr) ; df %>% mutate_all(as.character) %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(name = lst(name)) %>% transpose() %>% map(~.x %>% extract2('name') %>% lst() %>% set_names(.x %>% extract2('group'))) %>% flatten()`, but I'm confident that `split` is what Hadley would write. Note you can avoid the first call by using `data_frame`.

Comment: all `purrr`: `df %>% dmap(as.character) %>% transpose() %>% split_by('group') %>% map(transpose) %>% map('name') %>% map(flatten_chr)`

Comment: tidyverse vs. basic R knowledge, This is turning into a civil war.

Comment: Managed to get rid of the pesky `base::as.character` and simplify a bit: `df %>% map(parse_character) %>% transpose() %>% split_by('group') %>% at_depth(2, 'name') %>% simplify_all()` ...but now I'm just playing golf against somebody with a hole-in-one. Also, see Hadley pipe `split` in the examples of `?purrr::map2`.

Comment: `df %>% split(x = as.character(.$name), f = as.character(.$group, drop = T))`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no such function yet in the tidyverse as far as I know. Thus, you will have to write your own:

```
split_tibble <- function(tibble, col = 'col') tibble %>% split(., .[, col])
```

Then:

```
dflist <- split_tibble(df, 'group')
```

results in a list of dataframes:

> ```
> > dflist
> $a
>   group name
> 1     a    A
> 2     a    B
>
> $b
>   group name
> 3     b    C
> 4     b    D
>
> > sapply(dflist, class)
>            a            b 
> "data.frame" "data.frame"
> ```

To get the desired output, you'll have to extend the function a bit:

```
split_tibble <- function(tibble, column = 'col') {
  tibble %>% split(., .[,column]) %>% lapply(., function(x) x[,setdiff(names(x),column)])
}
```

Now:

```
split_tibble(df, 'group')
```

results in:

> ```
> $a
> [1] A B
> Levels: A B C D
>
> $b
> [1] C D
> Levels: A B C D
> ```

Considering the alternatives in the comments and both answers, leads to the following conclusion: using the base R alternative `split(df$name, df$group)` is much wiser.

Comment: @Cath The point is loading 20 packages at once and then creating function that uses base R and a pipe, how can't you see the point? *<sigh>*

Comment: @Jaap, how does the split function (as in split(df$name, df$group)) know what names correspond to what group? I ask because the inputs are two vectors, not the original data frame with information on matching rows and columns. The solution worked for me, but wanted to understand the underlying logic.

Comment: @NBK Whe using `split(df$name, df$group)` the split function splits `df$name` according to the unique values of `df$group`. So, for each `a` in `df$group`, the split function-function takes the corresponding values from `df$name`.

Comment: I see. Makes sense.

Comment: @Jaap I used the function `group_by()` and then `group_split()`ona dataframe  to obtain a list of n dataframes based on those groups. How do I proceed to create n dataframes from that list, one for each group?

Answer (score 3):

With the new `group_map` function of dplyr, you can write

```
library(dplyr)
lst <- df %>% group_by(group) %>% 
              group_map(~.x)
```

The `group_map` function takes a formula which it applies to each group and returns the result as list. The function can be specified as a formula - and the identity formula is then `~.x`.

It is complicated to get the result as a named list using the above method because [there could be multiple grouping columns](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/4223). Therefore, it is currently easier to define it yourself;

```
names(lst) <- df %>% group_by(group) %>%
                     group_map(~.y) %>%
                     unlist()
```

In the formula-language `.y` means the key (which in your case will be either `"a"` or `"b"`).

Answer (score 1):

Use tidyverse

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df$ID <- 1:nrow(df)  # unique variable
lst <- df %>% spread(group, name) %>% select(-ID) %>% as.list()
lapply(lst, function(x) x[!is.na(x)])
```

Comment: The space bar is usually not that difficult to hit. Using it will immensely improve readability of your code, in particular if you are fond of piping.

Comment: @Roland, totally agree and it's even easier when using RStudio shortcuts (shift + cmd + m on a mac produce a pipe including spaces before and after)

Comment: What are you using ID column for ? does not look like you are using it reference anywhere ?